# Netgear R6400v2 enable incoming IPv6

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, netgear-router

I've got a Netgear R6400v2 running V1.0.4.98_10.0.71 and have IPv6 enabled on it (and by my ISP). From an external network, I'm able to ping and connect to the router itself,  but am unable to connect to any of the devices inside the network. It appears that the router is blocking incoming requests. I am fairly confident it is being blocked by the router as I've tried with both MacOS and Windows 10 - both of whom have their firewalls configured to allow external pings. I will further clarify that outgoing IPv6 (and regular browsing, and test-ipv6) work from both computers.

I've disabled the routers VPN functionality already (as the configuration interface stated IPv6 doesn't work with the router's VPN server enabled).

Where can I configure it to allow incoming requests? It appears as the router is acting as a firewall on IPv6, but I can't find anywhere to configure its IPv6 port blocking.

Comment: No ping or netstat response? And no connection status on client?

Comment: I'm testing using a remote ping service. Neither computer responded, and the Mac showed no connections with Netstat. I'll start a server somewhere to confirm client connection status today.

Comment: IS router on auto config+setup?

Comment: Yes. It auto-configured to the 'DHCP' mode, with 'Use DHCP ' set for LAN Setup, and get DNS automatically from ISP